# Google Maps Javascript API v3 won't load in meteor project, net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, meteor

As the title suggests, the API won't even load. I get the following error in the console:

```
csi.gstatic.com/csi?v=2&s=mapsapi3&action=apiboot2&rt=main.35&libraries=pla…1_5_0,11_6_C,11_7_12300064,11_8_0,11_9_0,11_10_0,11_11_0,11_12_0,11_13_0:1 
GET https://csi.gstatic.com/csi?v=2&s=mapsapi3&action=apiboot2&rt=main.35&libra…,11_5_0,11_6_C,11_7_12300064,11_8_0,11_9_0,11_10_0,11_11_0,11_12_0,11_13_0 
net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

API Setup in router.js

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function() {
  GoogleMaps.load({
    key: 'MY API KEY',
    libraries: 'places'
  });
  this.next();
}, { only: 'dealSubmit'});
```

I'm using the jeremy:geocomplete package.

I'm sure the API key is enabled. I have authorized localhost/* as a referrer.
I'm also sure the API key is correct.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess you are using some kind of adblockers. It  is blocking it. Try after disabling it.

Comment: You were 100% correct, thanks. That cleared up the error. Now the lookup just doesn't work for some reason. Let the fun begin in figuring this out.

Comment: Same problem with Facebook API, same error, same solution!